# How can I reverse geocode through bing using javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, bing, mkreversegeocoder

I have the address of a location, and I'm trying to find its latitude/longitude from the bing service using javascript or java. How would I do this?

Comment: That's just geocoding, not reverse-geocoding. See the REST API documentation of Bing Maps to geocode an address - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701711.aspx. Using the API requires you to signup (free) for a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the new way to do that is by using their REST service documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx.

For example:

> [http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?key=BingMapsKey&query=White
>   House](http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?key=BingMapsKey&query=White%20House)
>     or
>   [http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?key=BingMapsKey&query=1600
>   Pennsylvania Ave NW Washington, DC](http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?key=BingMapsKey&query=1600%20Pennsylvania%20Ave%20NW%20Washington,%20DC)